# Parent to child object pass for one to many relationship with multilevel while inserting new child object . Ios Core data

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, relationship, one-to-many

I am having issue with coredata saving in background. I am implementing the following model :

- MasterManagedObject (of type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
- MainManagedObjectContext (of type NSMainQueueConcurrencyType & is child of MasterManagedObject)
- TemporaryManagedObjectContext (of type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType & is child of MainManagedObjectContext)

Code is  :

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)masterManagedObjectContext {
    if (_masterManagedObjectContext) {
        return _masterManagedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self storeCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        dime(@"Here in master context");
        _masterManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_masterManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _masterManagedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext {
    if (_mainManagedObjectContext) {
        return _mainManagedObjectContext;
    }

    _mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mainManagedObjectContext setParentContext:self.masterManagedObjectContext];
    return _mainManagedObjectContext;
}

+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)temporaryWorkerContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *tempMOContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tempMOContext.parentContext = [[DDPersist manager] mainManagedObjectContext];
    return tempMOContext;
}
```

Saving contexts:

```
+ (void)saveTempContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    if (!error) {
        [[DDPersist manager] saveMainContext];
        dime(@"Temp Context Saved");
    } else {
        dime(@"Temp Context Error  = %@",error);
    }
}

- (void)saveMainContext {
    [[[DDPersist manager] mainManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[[DDPersist manager] mainManagedObjectContext] save:&error];
        if(!error){
            //Write to disk after saving on the main UI context
            [[DDPersist manager] saveMasterContext];
            dime(@"main Context Saved");
        } else {
            dime(@"Main Context Error  = %@",error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)saveMasterContext {
    [self.masterManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.masterManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if(error){
            dime(@"Master Context Saved");
        } else {
            dime(@"Master Context Error  %@", error);
            if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                dime(@"Master Context Error NOT ON BACKGROUND CONTEXT! WILL AUTOMATICALLY PERSIST ON MAIN CTX!");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I am using above to create new spaceChecklistItems objects in background thread as below :
    //space is parent of spaceCheckListItem with one to many relationship.

```
                    __block NSManagedObjectID *spaceObjectID = [space objectID];
                    //Background thread starts here 
                    [DDPersist performTaskOnBackgroundCtxWithParentChildScheme:^(NSManagedObjectContext *bgCtx) {

                        Space *localSpace = (Space*)[bgCtx objectWithID:spaceObjectID];

                        for(NSDictionary * spaceChecklistItemDict in spaceChecklistItems) {
                            SpaceChecklistItem * spaceChecklistItem = [SpaceChecklistItemService importSpaceChecklistItem:spaceChecklistItemDict space:localSpace];
                            NSAssert(spaceChecklistItem, @"invalid SpaceChecklistItem at import!");
                            if(!spaceChecklistItem) continue;

                        }
                        [bgCtx obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:bgCtx.insertedObjects.allObjects error:nil];

                        [DDPersist saveTempContext:bgCtx];
                    }];
```

The method(importSpaceChecklistItem) used in the background context is as under  :

```
+ (SpaceChecklistItem*)importSpaceChecklistItem:(NSDictionary*)itemDict space:(Space*)space {

NSNumber *spaceChecklistItemId  = [itemDict objectForKey:@"id"];

NSString * inspectionStatus ;
if ([itemDict objectForKey:@"inspectionStatus"]) {
    inspectionStatus = [itemDict objectForKey:@"inspectionStatus"];
} else {
    inspectionStatus = @"UNDECIDED";
}

NSString * notes = [itemDict objectForKey:@"notes"];
MOC * ctx = space.managedObjectContext;

SpaceChecklistItem * spaceChecklistItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SpaceChecklistItem class])
                                                                        inManagedObjectContext:ctx];


spaceChecklistItem.spaceChecklistItemId = spaceChecklistItemId;
spaceChecklistItem.space = space;// This is the relationship saving & not working.
spaceChecklistItem.inspectionStatus = inspectionStatus;
spaceChecklistItem.notes=notes;
spaceChecklistItem.sync = @NO;    
return spaceChecklistItem;
}
```

The main issue is performance issue. I want to speedup for loop : for(NSDictionary * spaceChecklistItemDict in spaceChecklistItems) from the above. And want to all the processing into background. This for loop might contain more than 50000 iterations. which usually take time(about 3 minutes) to save into coredata.Data is saving if i use a single thread & keep for loop in the single thread child of main(not the master context) . But this one to many relationship giving me issues & i am struggling with it for a long.

I read many stackoverflow questions & many othe articles . But cant get this sort out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are not creating any `spaceChecklistItem` in the import method.

Comment: @Mundi , Sorry i missed that line while copying from actual code to here on stackOverFlow & removing extra code. I updated my code now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run Instruments?

Run the Time Profiler and look at what is taking the most amount of time.

Post that trace to your question so that others can see it as well.

Comment: I can add that, No problem. But i am getting issues saving the context currently. Instruments is completely different thing. If somehow i can get this context saving resolved then i think it would resolve all the issues.I am getting relationship fault there.

Comment: Instruments is your go to tool for performance issues.  It is the first place you go to look to see WHY something is slow.  This saving issue, if it is not producing an error, needs to be looked at in Instruments.  Otherwise you are just wasting time guessing and assuming.  This might not even be a Core Data problem, it might be a threading problem, might be a data problem.  You don't KNOW until you run it under a time profiler.  Seriously, that is step one.